# Finding multiple instances in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, rdbms

I have two tables in my database:

Events:

[image]

Student:

[image]

I have an  SQL query that queries the 'Events' table to show me when a student has coming in (where In_Or_Out = 'In')later than 08:40 in one week period:

```
SELECT RFID,Event_Date_Time
FROM Events
WHERE Events.Event_Date_Time BETWEEN #3/24/2015# And #3/17/2015# AND Events.In_Or_Out='In' AND Format(Event_Date_Time,'HH:MM')>#8:40:00#
```

Now I'm trying to find out if a student has been late twice or more in one week. I've tried the following SQL query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Events
WHERE Events.Event_Date_Time BETWEEN #3/24/2015# And #3/17/2015# AND Events.In_Or_Out='In' AND Format(Event_Date_Time,'HH:MM')>#8:40:00#
GROUP BY RFID
HAVING COUNT(RFID)>1
```

Anyone know the correct query?

Comment: Note that posting images in your question is generally a bad idea. For one, they are often blocked (like for me here at work) . But also, what if I want to reproduce your setup - you expect me to type it all in when you could have just put in the table structure as text? The same goes for the sample data. If you make it easy for us to replicate your problem you are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: @Turophile Sorry about posting the image, I wasn't sure how to upload a table through another method.

Comment: You can just paste it in as text and then format it as code. Putting in graphics isn't unacceptable or breaking any rule - it's just that text is _usually_ the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample queries, it appears *Event_Date_Time* is Date/Time datatype.  So I suggest you use `TimeValue()` to examine the time components as Date/Time type instead of converting them to String with `Format()`.

```sql
SELECT Events.RFID, Count(*)
FROM Events
WHERE
        Events.Event_Date_Time BETWEEN #3/17/2015# And #3/24/2015#
    AND Events.In_Or_Out='In'
    AND TimeValue(Events.Event_Date_Time) > #08:40:00#
GROUP BY Events.RFID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want to also see the names or other information from your *Student* table, join the `GROUP BY` query back to *Student* on *RFID*.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I apologize for uploading the tables as image, it was the only way I knew how, thanks again!

Comment: The images weren't an issue for me because the SQL gave me all the information I needed for this one.  However, in many other questions, I think Turophile's suggested practice would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.RFID, s.FORENAME, s.SURENAME, count(e.*) AS LATE, 
FROM Events e
INNER JOIN students s
on s.RFID = e.RFID
WHERE e.Event_Date_Time BETWEEN '3/24/2015' And '3/17/2015' 
    AND e.In_Or_Out='In' 
    AND time(e.Event_Date_Time)>'8:40:00'
GROUP BY e.RFID, s.FORENAME, s.SURENAME
HAVING COUNT(e.*)>1
```